# printf prints invalid characters after each number

Tags: c, printf

On calling the print_compressed() (code given below), the program prints characters properly, but after printf() is executed (to print numerical values), an additional character is also printed. This char is not visible on the terminal. But on saving the output to a file, it is represented as '^@' (using nano editor).

```
void modify(char *ch, int *cons, char *vow)
{
    if (strchr(vowels, *ch) == NULL) {
        if (*vow) {
            putchar(*vow);
            *vow = 0;
        }
        ++*cons;
    } else {
        if (*cons) {
            printf("%i", *cons);
            *cons = 0;
        }
        if (*vow != *ch)
            putchar(*vow);
        *vow = *ch;
    }    
}

void print_compressed(char *s)
{
    putchar(toupper(*(s++)));
    int curr = 0;
    int cons = 0;
    char vow = 0;
    while (s[curr]) {
        modify(s + curr, &cons, &vow);
        ++curr;
    }
    modify(s + curr, &cons, &vow);
    putchar('\n');
}
```

> Input :
>   aaabcdefee
>
> Expected Output : 
>   Aa3e1e
>
> Output on terminal is same as expected
>
> Output when output is saved as file : 
>   A^@a3^@e1^@e

Comment: Your output and expected output are the same.

Comment: @Blaze maybe it's an editor issue? see _" This char is not visible on the terminal"_

Comment: I'll show an image , wait

Comment: The `^@` is a null byte. Maybe you are writing the null bytes at the end of the strings too?

Comment: @SouravGhosh that's possible. I thought that maybe OP accidentally pasted the same snippet twice. I know I'd probably do that. :)

Comment: Anyway I got the Selection Highlighter installed and it highlights them as the same, so either it doesn't work with those hidden symbols or the hidden symbols were removed when posting the snippet.

Comment: I added a link to the image

Comment: I’m suspicious of the `modify(s + cur, …)` line, but an MCVE ([MCVE]) would help.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I agree. I did that. Also, there is a ^@ after the first A.

Comment: @xing : I recommend turning that into an answer

Comment: @xing Thanks, that worked!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at your program logic in the `modify` function.
If you find a vowel, you set `*vow = 0` if it was not 0 before.
In the next step, if you don't find a vowel, you output `*vow`, which is
a null-byte. Afterwards, you set `*vow = *ch`.

So always when it does not find a vowel and had found a vowel before,
and a non-vowel before that, a 0-byte is printed.

Rethink your logic :)

Or simply change

```
if (*vow != *ch)
    putchar(*vow)
```

to

```
if (*vow != *ch)
    if (*vow) putchar(*vow);
```

Comment: Or `if (*vow != *ch && *vow != '\0') putchar(*vow);`, which some people would shorten to `if (*vow != *ch && *vow) putchar(*vow);`.  Personally, I think the symmetry of the longer version is better, and the compiler will produce the same code either way.